# web worker delegation (subworkers) not working

Tags: javascript, delegation, web-worker

I can't seem to get the Web Worker delegation example from http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/complete/workers.html#delegation to work on Chrome, Firefox or Safari. Web Inspector/firebug consoles are silent.

What's up with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to post on such an old thread. But the situation of subworker support as of 1.1.17 is like follows:

- supported by: Firefox, Edge (Windows 10)
- not (yet) supported by: Opera, Chrome, Safari, Android Browser (Nougat)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about Firefox, but this hasn't even been implemented in Chrome or Safari yet. [Here's Chrome's issue about it](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31666).